# How to tell c++ that 9+1 should be 1 and not 10?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I have an array of 10 integers, and k is an integer that loops through the array.
Whenever I do 'k = k+1' , one is added to 'k', (if 'k' is 7, then it becomes 8). But if 'k' reaches till 9, I dont want 'k+1' evaluate to 10, I want it to become 1;

I considered using a function like this:

```
void add_one(int &k){
   if(k == 9){
      k = 1;
   }else{
      k = k+1;
   }
}
```

and whenever i want to add one to 'k':

```
add_one(k);
```

Then I found out about operator overloading, but it was very confusing and think there must be a better way. Can we tell c++ that whenever it sees k+1 where k = 9, it must return 1 and not 10?

Comment: If it's an array, wouldn't you want it to go from 9 to 0?

Comment: For Bjarne's sake, why would you want to change the meaning of `+` for integers? What's next? You want to change the value of 3?

Comment: What is the meaning of better ? You could possibly write the if statement using the ternary operator or use % as suggested in the answers.

Comment: @chris i want the index 0 to be skipped, whenever i loop through the array, because it stores a completely different value than all the other indexes

Comment: @A.06 you make it sound like whatever you are storing on index 0 doesn't belong in the array. *wink wink*

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Actually that array is of boolean values and i want index 0 to always be false, (all other values are changed throughout the program)

Comment: What? It's, like, four lines, and you've already written it, and it's perfectly clear what it does and now you want overload '+' or something?  What?  Why are you wasting your time with this, or ours for that matter? Do you not have any real bugs to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
k = k % 9 + 1;
```

Comment: Yes thats a good idea but is there a better way, so that whenever i am adding 1 to k, i just have to do k = k+1 and c++ will take care of the rest?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't notice the 1 based index. Fixing.

Comment: @A.06: You could, through operator overloading, but the thing you end up with would no longer be an `int`. It's probably best to keep integers as integers.

Comment: @GregHewgill i had searched for operator overloading, but it is very confusing

Comment: @A.06: Yes, I don't recommend using operator overloading for this purpose.

Comment: You want to overload operator+ so that it adds integers in a non-standard way! Please don't ever mention this in a job interview.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the meaning of `+` for a builtin type. If you write your own class whose instances behave like numbers, then you can make `+` do what you want.

One way is to just make a thin class that wraps an existing type:

```
class mynumber {
  int n;
public:
  mynumber(int n_init) : n(n_init) { }
};
```

Now you can write overloads for `mynumber`, as well as things like conversion operators and so on.

The key is that overloading works with classes (and enumerations).

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(k == 9)` to `if(k >= 9)`  in the function `void add_one(int k)`.  Remove the `&` in `void add_one(int &k)`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



void add_one(int k){
   if(k >= 9){
      k = 1;
   }else{
      k = k+1;
   }
   cout<<" k="<<k<<"  \n";
}


int main(void)
{
  int k ;
  for(k=0;k<20;k++)  
  {
      cout<<"input "<<k<<" ";
      add_one(k);
  }

  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
input 0  k=1
input 1  k=2
input 2  k=3
input 3  k=4
input 4  k=5
input 5  k=6
input 6  k=7
input 7  k=8
input 8  k=9
input 9  k=1
input 10  k=1
input 11  k=1
input 12  k=1
input 13  k=1
input 14  k=1
input 15  k=1
input 16  k=1
input 17  k=1
input 18  k=1
input 19  k=1

Press any key to continue
```

Comment: instead of using the + sign i am using my function add_one,
so this function will never let 'k' be greater than 9, but thank you for that, it is better to be safe.